# What does the '&' selector select?

Tags: sass

In [this](http://codepen.io/aniketpant/pen/4/1) codepen there is a css selector `&:hover` what does that selector match?

Comment: If you looked carefully, you could probably have seen that there's (SCSS) written next to the CSS tab headline.

Comment: @Truth: assuming that comment was directed at me, then yes: I did see that. I was, however, addressing the explicit statement in the question itself: "...there is a css selector `&:hover`." Perhaps I should have made that more clear, though.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I believe the ampersand is a [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) feature. From the docs:

[Referencing Parent Selectors: &](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#parent-selector)

> Sometimes it’s useful to use a nested rule’s parent selector in other
>   ways than the default. For instance, you might want to have special
>   styles for when that selector is hovered over or for when the body
>   element has a certain class. In these cases, you can explicitly
>   specify where the parent selector should be inserted using the &
>   character.

Answer (score 51):

Exactly. In Sass you could have something like this...

```
 div {
    background: green;

    p {
        background: red;

        &:hover {
            background: blue;
        }

        &:active {
           background: blue; 
        }
    }   
}
```

...which when converted to CSS would become this:

```
div {
    background: green;
}

div p {
    background: red;
}

div p:hover {
    background: blue;
}

div p:active {
    background: blue;
}
```

Edit: from &hover: to &:hover

Comment: On your second code block, shouldn't it be `div p:hover { background: blue; }` and  `div p:active { background: blue; }` ? I just mention it to clear it up...

Comment: Yes. Of course. I apologise. Stupid mistake. Fixed.

Answer (score 5):

One usage that is less widely known is you can add the ampersand to the end of a style so the parent selector becomes the child.

eg:

```
 h3
   font-size: 20px
   margin-bottom: 10px

 .some-parent-selector &
   font-size: 24px
   margin-bottom: 20px
```

becomes,

```
  h3 {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }

  .some-parent-selector h3 {
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
```

you can read more about & use here

http://thesassway.com/intermediate/referencing-parent-selectors-using-ampersand