# Sass: & when defining nested classes

Tags: css, sass

I am learning [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/guide). I am going through nested class section. It has following snippet.

```
nav {
  ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
  }

  li { display: inline-block; }

  a {
    display: block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}
```

In my project Sass is used. And nested classes are written with the help of `&` operator. eg. The same snippet is written as:

```
nav {
  & ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
  }

  & li { display: inline-block; }

  & a {
    display: block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}
```

Both snippet generates same CSS as:

```
nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}
nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

What I want to know is **what is this `&` operator doing here? Can it be omitted?**

Comment: It's referencing parent selectors. Check below link. http://stackoverflow.com/a/11335114/5363447

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both snippet generates same CSS as because you have a space after the &, but if you delete the space you should get

```
navul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
navli {
  display: inline-block;
}
nava {
  display: block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

But in this case it makes no sense, so we use it when you have a class after the **&** like this:

```
nav {
  &.class1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
  }

  &.class2 { display: inline-block; }

  &.class3 {
    display: block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}
```

You will get:

```
nav.class1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
  }

nav.class2 { display: inline-block; }

nav.class3 {
    display: block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I got the difference.

Answer (score 0):

After delving into documentation I found explanation of `&` [here](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#parent-selector). So basically `&` is a parent-selector. From doc:

> Sometimes it’s useful to use a nested rule’s parent selector in other
>   ways than the default. For instance, you might want to have special
>   styles for when that selector is hovered over or for when the body
>   element has a certain class. In these cases, you can explicitly
>   specify where the parent selector should be inserted using the &
>   character. For example:

**SCSS**:

```
a {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  &:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
  body.firefox & { font-weight: normal; }
}
```

**CSS**:

```
    a {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

body.firefox a {
  font-weight: normal;
}
```